# Excel VBA. How to set default value in a combo box and color of the value

Tags: excel, vba

two questions.

1) How to set a default value `1` in the combo box variable `curCombo`, that when user creates that, it will automatically get a default value `1`.

2) How to set that a value `1` shows green background, a value `2` shows yellow background and the value `3` shows red background.

```
Sub ComboBox()

Dim curCombo As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws

    Set rng = .Cells.Item(ActiveCell.row, 3)


    Set curCombo = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                          Left:=rng.Left, _
                                          Top:=rng.Top, _
                                          Width:=rng.Width, _
                                          Height:=rng.Height)

    With curCombo
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3

        .ControlFormat.AddItem "1", 1
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "2", 2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "3", 3
        .Name = "myCombo" 

    End With



End With
```

End Sub
code here

Comment: Use the `.ControlFormat.Value` Ex `curCombo.ControlFormat.Value = 1`

Comment: Didn't understand your 2nd question. Background color of what?

Comment: I mean that I would like to implement a basic traffic light solution into cells. A value 1 indicates green, a value 2 indicates yellow and a value 3 indicates red.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ComboBox()

Dim curCombo As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws

    Set rng = .Cells.Item(ActiveCell.Row, 3)


    Set curCombo = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                          Left:=rng.Left, _
                                          Top:=rng.Top, _
                                          Width:=rng.Width, _
                                          Height:=rng.Height)

    With curCombo
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3

        .ControlFormat.AddItem "1", 1
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "2", 2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "3", 3
        **.ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1**
        .Name = "myCombo"
    End With


End With



End Sub
```

Comment: ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1 --> I can confirm that this works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The simple way og selecting the first item in a combobox in excel:

ComboBox.ListIndex = 0