# How do I change the selection of a combo box to a default value when text box content changes in Access 2013 VBA

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, mouseevent, ms-access-2013

I'm needing to change the selections of two combo boxes to the a default value when the contents of a text box change. I have an audit trail tied to the fields, and I need the user to select a new 'change reason' and 'change initiator' (the combo boxes Qtr1Date1Changer and Qtr1Date1Initiator) when an inventory date changes (the text box Qtr1Date1). I have an AfterUpdate event for the text box to record the new date in the audit table; can I add something here to change the contents of the two combo boxes if the date changes to a default value?

```
    Private Sub Qtr1Date1_AfterUpdate()
       Call LogChanges(StoreCode) 
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should always look for [simular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775146/excel-vba-how-to-set-default-value-in-a-combo-box-and-color-of-the-value) SO questions and explain what you tried so far and what problem you encountered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685120/1531971 might also be similar.

Comment: Thanks, @JDV, I saw this one when I was looking for similar but just wasn't sure about all the excel stuff in it. Oi.

Comment: @Erika, reading other Q&A will help you understand your own problem better. You need to exhaust those first to be sure this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I did it, got it to work with that one. Added Qtr1Date1Changer = "<Select>"

Comment: I promise I read tons of other questions, just didn't know what I was looking at. Sorry. I'm less than a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve:

```
   Private Sub Qtr1Date1_AfterUpdate()
       Call LogChanges(StoreCode) 
       Qtr1Date1Changer = "<Select>"
       Qtr1Date1Reason = "<Select>"
   End Sub
```